# How do I get the camera functionality to display in only one tab bar item?

Tags: ios, swift

I am currently creating a QR scanner/ reader application in Xcode 10. I have a Tab controller that has two tab bar items.

1.) Home

2.) QR Scanner

Although, my code works and I can scan a QR code in the "second view controller", whenever I switch to the "first view controller", it still scans the QR code when i don't want it to. If you have any tips on how I can fix this issue, it would be much appreciated.

**First View Controller:**

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController{
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

**Second View Controller:**

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {
    var video = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer()

    @IBOutlet weak var square: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Creating session
        let session = AVCaptureSession()

        //Define Capture device
        let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video)

        do {
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice!)
            session.addInput(input)
        } catch {
            print (">>>>Error")
        }

        let output = AVCaptureMetadataOutput ()
        session.addOutput(output)

        output.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)

        output.metadataObjectTypes = [AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.qr]

        video = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session)
        video.frame = view.layer.bounds
        view.layer.addSublayer(video)

        self.view.bringSubviewToFront(square)

        session.startRunning()
    }

    func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        if metadataObjects != nil && metadataObjects.count != 0 {
            if let object = metadataObjects[0] as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject{
                if object.type == AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.qr{
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "QR code", message: object.stringValue, preferredStyle: .alert)
                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Retake", style: .default, handler: nil))

                    present(alert,animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend adding the session as a member variable in your class instead of only the viewDidLoad() method.

Now in your viewWillAppear() method you can call the session.startRunning() and in viewWillDisappear you want to call session.stopRunning()

Here is a basic layout:

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {
    let session = AVCaptureSession()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        // any setup you may need
    }

    override func viewWillAppear() {
        // ensure everything is setup correctly

        session.startRunning()
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear() {
        // anything before navigating away

        session.stopRunning()
    }
}
```

Comment: I will let you know my results very soon.

Comment: @tharriott please mark as the approved answer if this helped you :)

Comment: in your example you are overriding `viewDidLoad` twice

Comment: Whoops! Thank you. @PeterPajchl

Answer (score 0):

You have started the `AVCaptureSession` session but you don't explicitly stop it. Whenever switching between controllers the system might keep the controller in memory.

You will want to execute `session.stopRunning()` prior to navigating away from the controller and clean up. E.g. in `viewWillDisappear` or simiilar.

Ref: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturesession/1385661-stoprunning

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your assistance. After reviewing my code I realized that what I had to do was override the viewDidAppear() and viewDidDisappear().

**Working Code:**

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {

    let session = AVCaptureSession()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        // any setup you may need
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        session.startRunning()
        print("Start running")
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        session.stopRunning()
        print ("Stop running")
    }

}
```